# Javascript event triggered by pressing space

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am trying to get an event to trigger when I am on a page and press <kbd>space</kbd>, but I can't figure it out. Currently I am trying to use jQuery to accomplish a satisfying result.

I have tried using `keydown`, `keyup` and `keypress`, but it seems that you can only use it if you are actually inputting something to a form or field.

What I want is to trigger an alert when <kbd>space</kbd> is pressed.

Comment: Posting some relevant code that you have already would be helpful.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

These events bubble up, so if you're trying to trigger the event wherever your focus is (ie. not in an input), just bind a handler on `window`:

```
$(window).keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.key === ' ' || e.key === 'Spacebar') {
    // ' ' is standard, 'Spacebar' was used by IE9 and Firefox < 37
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log('Space pressed')
  }
})
```

Also see [the list of all `.key` values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values).

Comment: On Firefox, this intercepted Ctrl+J, so I changed the first condition to `e.charCode === 32`.

Comment: From the answer right below: "`0` works in mozilla and `32` in other browsers". This is probably not relevant anymore, but you should be using the modern [.key](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) instead anyway.

Comment: Works with `e.key === ' '` in Chrome, Firefox and Safari

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
$('input:text').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 0 || e.keyCode == 32) // `0` works in mozilla and `32` in other browsers
       console.log('space pressed');
});
```

Comment: Op said without using any `input`

Answer (score 5):

Try to bind your key event listener to the jQuery $(document) object;

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).keydown(function(e) {
          if (e.keyCode == '32') {
            alert('space');
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

This code can be used:

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 0 || e.keyCode == 32) {
    console.log('Space pressed');
  }
});
```

**Explaination:**
The `$(window).keypress(function(e)` waits for the user to press any key and stores the data of the key pressed in the argument 'e'.
Then `if (e.keyCode == 0 || e.keyCode == 32)` checks if the code of the key pressed is equal to the code of spacebar, that is 0 or 32. If this returns false then any other key is pressed and the code ends.
**Some commonly used keycodes:**

- backspace:8
- tab:9
- enter:13
- shift:16
- ctrl:17
- alt:18
- caps lock:20
- escape:27
- (space):32
- 0-9:48-57
- a-z:65-90
- numpad0-numpad9:96-105